# Aptana 3 - Promote to project create empty directory

Tags: aptana3

I just upgrade aptana to version 3.  The promote to project create a new empty directory at the root of my workspace.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, the directory to promote need to be at the root level of the workspace.

Thanks

Comment: This Q&A should be in the FAQ of Aptana itself. Thank you so very much, kind sir.